# contar horas repetidas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día, tengo la siguiente consulta que me devuelve en el segundo campo, el total de registros que obtiene mi consulta, y en el tercero, la hora en la que el cliente se registró. lo que deseo, es tener un campo donde obtenga la cantidad de veces que esa hora se repite, un resultado así:

```
nom_clien                                Total_registrados Periodo     Periodo_Repetido
---------------------------------------- ----------------- ----------- ----------------
HAYDAR MENDEZ SOLEDAD DEL CARMEN         8                 10          1
CAAMAL CARRILLO FILIBERTO                8                 12          2
CONSERVAS LA COSTENA,S.A DE C.V          8                 12          2
SALAS AYALA UBALDO                       8                 14          1
ARGAEZ LIZAMA MA.DEL SOCORRO             8                 15          1
CHAN CAN MARIA DEL CARMEN                8                 16          3
CHAN CHAN ALFREDO                        8                 16          3
NAVARRETE MEDINA MARTHA EUGENIA          8                 16          3
```

El query que tengo es el siguiente:

```
SELECT nom_clien,(select COUNT(fe_registro) from cliente where fe_registro is not null) as Total_registrados, DATEPART(HH, fe_registro) as Periodo
FROM cliente
where fe_registro is not null
GROUP BY nom_clien,DATEPART(HH, fe_registro)
order by periodo
```

los datos base son estos:

```
nom_clien                                fe_registro
---------------------------------------- -----------------------
ARGAEZ LIZAMA MA.DEL SOCORRO             2019-10-10 15:27:37.473
SALAS AYALA UBALDO                       2019-10-10 14:54:17.567
HAYDAR MENDEZ SOLEDAD DEL CARMEN         2019-09-23 10:38:03.187
CAAMAL CARRILLO FILIBERTO                2019-09-23 12:28:04.197
CONSERVAS LA COSTENA,S.A DE C.V          2019-09-23 12:28:04.197
NAVARRETE MEDINA MARTHA EUGENIA          2019-10-10 16:05:32.270
CHAN CHAN ALFREDO                        2019-10-10 16:06:57.167
CHAN CAN MARIA DEL CARMEN                2019-10-10 16:07:28.733
```

Comment: la tabla tiene información de un único día?

Comment: como máximo, tendrá información de 2 días seguidos, por ejemplo, tendrá información de hoy, 11 de octubre, y mañana, 12 de octubre

Comment: Puedes mostrar los datos de la tabla?. Por otro lado, supongamos un usuario registrado a las 10 de un día y otro a las 10 del día siguiente; el resultado Periodo_Repetido debe mostrar 2 para ese horario?

Comment: actualicé la pregunta con los datos de fe_registro que almaceno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un cálculo sencillo usando la clausula `OVER`.

```
SELECT nom_clien,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cliente WHERE fe_registro IS NOT NULL) as Total_registrados, 
    DATEPART(HH, fe_registro) as Periodo,
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(HH, fe_registro))
FROM cliente
WHERE fe_registro IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY periodo;
```

En caso de necesitar que se divida por día, solo agregas la parte del día a la definición de la partición, tal como lo harías en un GROUP BY.

Agrego una prueba de rendimiento entre las opciones de utilizar funciones de agregado con ventanas y subconsultas. Esto es para demostrar que la opción presentada originalmente es la que mejor rendimiento tiene en general. Por favor, tengan cuidado al ejecutar esta prueba para no borrar tablas reales. Esta prueba se puede modificar para quitar las últimas dos columnas y ver la diferencia que genera la ventana vacía `OVER()`.

```
USE tempdb;
GO
CREATE TABLE cliente(
    nom_clien varchar(100),
    fe_registro datetime);

INSERT INTO cliente 
SELECT 
    a.FirstName + ' ' + a.LastName,
    DATEADD( HH, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%23,'20191011')
FROM AdventureWorks2016.Person.Person a
CROSS 
JOIN (VALUES('0'),('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9')) x(n);

DECLARE @nom_Cliente        varchar(100),
        @TotalRegistrados   int,
        @Periodo            int,
        @Repetidos          int;

SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
PRINT 'Ejecución limpia'
SELECT @nom_Cliente      = nom_clien,
       @TotalRegistrados = 1,
       @Periodo          = DATEPART(HH, fe_registro),
       @Repetidos        = 1
FROM cliente
WHERE fe_registro IS NOT NULL;

PRINT '------------------------------------------------------------------------'
PRINT 'Ejecución con 2 subconsultas'

SELECT @nom_Cliente      = nom_clien,
       @TotalRegistrados = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cliente WHERE fe_registro IS NOT NULL), 
       @Periodo          = DATEPART(HH, fe_registro),
       @Repetidos        = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cliente i WHERE DATEPART(HH, i.fe_registro) =  DATEPART(HH, c.fe_registro) )
FROM cliente c
WHERE fe_registro IS NOT NULL;

PRINT '------------------------------------------------------------------------'
PRINT 'Ejecución con subconsulta y función de agregado con ventana'

SELECT @nom_Cliente      = nom_clien,
       @TotalRegistrados = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cliente WHERE fe_registro IS NOT NULL), 
       @Periodo          = DATEPART(HH, fe_registro),
       @Repetidos        = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(HH, fe_registro))
FROM cliente
WHERE fe_registro IS NOT NULL;

PRINT '------------------------------------------------------------------------'
PRINT 'Ejecución con funciones de agregado con ventanas (una de ellas vacía)'

SELECT @nom_Cliente      = nom_clien,
       @TotalRegistrados = COUNT(*) OVER(), 
       @Periodo          = DATEPART(HH, fe_registro),
       @Repetidos        = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(HH, fe_registro))
FROM cliente
WHERE fe_registro IS NOT NULL;

SET STATISTICS IO OFF;
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;

GO
--Descomentar esto solo en un ambiente seguro para no borrar una tabla real
--DROP TABLE cliente;
```

Comment: en este caso `Total_Registrados` sería simplemente `COUNT(*) OVER()`

Comment: Sí podría ser, pero he visto problemas de rendimiento cuando se usa OVER() sin ninguna partición. Voy a tratar de armar un ejemplo para agregarlo.

Comment: No creo que genere peor rendimiento que hacer un scan completo a la tabla nuevamente

Comment: Esa es la belleza de poder generar pruebas. Revisa lo que acabo de agregar a la respuesta para que lo compruebes por ti mismo.

Comment: Hay varios supuestos en esas pruebas, por ejemplo la cantidad de filas que tendría la tabla...por otro lado, cada consulta debería correr limpiando el cache entre ellas, cambiando el orden de ejecución, y más de una vez cada una

Comment: @Lamak Puedes limpiar el cache, pero hay gente que no tiene permisos para hacerlo. La ejecución limpia se encarga de poner los datos en cache y además nos da una medición base de la duración sin cálculos. Cambiar el orden de ejecución y la cantidad de ejecuciones no muestra diferencias en el comportamiento. La cantidad de filas también se puede alterar sin problema (agregando otro cross join o un top) y el comportamiento se mantiene.

Answer (score 2):

Una alternativa a la respuesta de Luis, seguramente menos performante, pero compatible con versiones antiguas de SQL Server, es usar una subconsulta para calcular las cantidades por período y anexar este resultado a tu consulta principal:

```
SELECT  c.nom_clien,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cliente WHERE fe_registro IS NOT NULL) as Total_registrados, 
        h.Periodo,
        h.Cantidad
        FROM cliente c
        INNER JOIN (SELECT  DATEPART(HH, fe_registro) as Periodo,
                            COUNT(*) as Cantidad
                            from cliente
                            WHERE fe_registro IS NOT NULL
                            group by DATEPART(HH, fe_registro)
        ) h
        ON DATEPART(HH, c.fe_registro) = h.Periodo
        WHERE fe_registro IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY c.nom_clien,
                 h.Periodo, 
                 h.Cantidad
        ORDER BY periodo;
```

Comment: Espero que nadie siga usando versiones anteriores a 2005, de otra forma mi solución no tendría problema. Pero más allá de eso, parece que tu opción es más eficiente según las pruebas que he hecho.